# oracle query for get 20 top agency which have pass issued

Tags: sql, oracle, top-n

I have a query which show datewise pass issued by agency. I wanted to get top 20 agency who have most pass issued here is my query

Comment: Sample data and expected results would help making your question clearer.

Comment: How is "agency" identified in your data?

Answer (score 1):

Nothing in your data id identifies "agency".  If I assume you mean "agent", you can get the top 20 by aggregating and then limiting the result.  In Oracle 12C+, you can use:

```
SELECT gp.agent_id, a.agent_name, COUNT(*)
FROM eofficeuat.gatepass gp INNER JOIN 
     eofficeuat.cnf_agents a
     ON gp.agent_id = a.agent_id INNER JOIN
     eofficeuat.cardprintlog_user u
     ON gp.agent_id = u.agent_id
WHERE gp.issuedatetime BETWEN DATE '2019-09-28' AND DATE '2019-09-29'
GROUP BY gp.agent_id, a.agent_name
ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC
FETCH FIRST 1 ROW ONLY;
```

In earlier versions, a subquery is needed:

```
SELECT *
FROM (SELECT gp.agent_id, a.agent_name, COUNT(*)
      FROM eofficeuat.gatepass gp INNER JOIN 
           eofficeuat.cnf_agents a
           ON gp.agent_id = a.agent_id INNER JOIN
           eofficeuat.cardprintlog_user u
           ON gp.agent_id = u.agent_id
      WHERE gp.issuedatetime BETWEEN DATE '2019-09-28' AND DATE '2019-09-29'
      GROUP BY gp.agent_id, a.agent_name
      ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC
     ) a
WHERE rownum <= 20;
```

Obviously, if you do mean "agency" and that is identified by different columns, you would just adjust the `SELECT` and `GROUP BY` clauses.

Also, I would advise you *never* to use `BETWEEN` on dates in Oracle.  There is a time component that might cause issues.

If you intend only times on '2019-09-28', then:

```
gp.issuedatetime >= DATE '2019-09-28' AND
gp.issuedatetime < DATE '2019-09-29'
```

If you intend *both* the 28th and 29th:

```
gp.issuedatetime >= DATE '2019-09-28' AND
gp.issuedatetime < DATE '2019-09-30'
```

Comment: great, the second query is working fine but not first query. thanks so much

Comment: @mdkamrul . . . Then you are using an older version of Oracle.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `LIMIT` clause(12c or higher version) with TOP 20 records as following:

```
SELECT eofficeuat.gatepass.agent_id, eofficeuat.cnf_agents.agent_name, COUNT(1) as cnt
FROM eofficeuat.gatepass INNER JOIN 
     eofficeuat.cnf_agents
     ON eofficeuat.gatepass.agent_id = eofficeuat.cnf_agents.agent_id INNER JOIN
     eofficeuat.cardprintlog_user
     ON eofficeuat.gatepass.agent_id = eofficeuat.cardprintlog_user.agent_id
WHERE eofficeuat.gatepass.issuedatetime BETWEN DATE '2019-09-28' AND DATE '2019-09-29'
GROUP BY eofficeuat.gatepass.agent_id, eofficeuat.cnf_agents.agent_name
ORDER BY cnt DESC
FETCH FIRST 20 ROWS ONLY; -- this will fetch top 20 agents
```

Cheers!!

Comment: this showing me this error
ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended
00933. 00000 -  "SQL command not properly ended"
*Cause:    
*Action:
Error at Line: 10 Column: 1

Comment: Which version of oracle? I have clearly mentioned that this solution will work for oracle 12 c or higher. I think your version is lower than 12c. For lower oracle versions, use the query same as shown in gordon's answer

Comment: I am using oracle 19c

Comment: Show me the exact query which you are executing